# Replace piece of json

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a big .json file with geodata. Its a piece of this file. It has a repeating structure.
I want to save info about "id" and "area_value" and remove or replace other data.

With this structure.

`{'Number':['id'],'Area sq.m.': ['area_value'],'Forest cov':'None','Status':'None'}`

What method can be optimal for solving this problem?

Thanks!

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "crs":{
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{
         "name":"EPSG:4326"
      }
   },
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "date_create":"15.03.2008",
            "statecd":"06",
            "cc_date_approval":null,
            "children":null,
            "adate":"23.08.2017",
            "cc_date_entering":"01.01.2014",
            "rifr_cnt":null,
            "parcel_build_attrs":null,
            "rifr":null,
            "sale_date":null,
            "area_unit":"055",
            "util_code":null,
            "util_by_doc":null,
            "area_value":115558.0,
            "application_date":null,
            "sale":null,
            "cad_unit":"383",
            "kvartal":"69:3:11",
            "parent_id":"69:3:11:248",
            "sale_cnt":null,
            "sale_doc_date":null,
            "date_cost":null,
            "category_type":"003008000000",
            "rifr_dep":null,
            "kvartal_cn":"69:03:0000011",
            "parent_cn":"69:03:0000011:248",
            "cn":"69:03:0000011:245",
            "is_big":false,
            "rifr_dep_info":null,
            "sale_dep":null,
            "sale_dep_uo":null,
            "parcel_build":false,
            "id":"69:3:11:245",
            "address":"\u0422\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c, \u0440-\u043d. \u0411\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439, \u0441/\u043f. \u0415\u0433\u043e\u0440\u044c\u0435\u0432\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0435, \u0434. \u041e\u0441\u0438\u043f\u043e\u0432\u043e",
            "area_type":"009",
            "parcel_type":"parcel",
            "sale_doc_num":null,
            "sale_doc_type":null,
            "sale_price":null,
            "cad_cost":139698.06,
            "fp":null,
            "center":{
               "x":33.14727379331379,
               "y":55.87764081906541
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service- you should show at least the work you have done so far.

Comment: First you will need to install the json package and then recursively dive into the data structure starting with the code snippet below

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try along the following lines:

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```